# Extra page with junk text is inserted at beginning of my document when changing font

Tags: fonts

TeXstudio newbie here. If I try to change the font of my document using the commands:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
```

The text changes like normal, but an extra page is inserted at the beginning of my document with the seemingly random text "lmrlmrlmsslmtt". I have no idea why this happens. If I delete the two above lines from my document, it will revert back to default font and the extra page with the weird text will be gone. This page will reappear at the beginning of my document regardless of what font I try to change my text to.

Please let me know how I can evade this problem...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There seems to be something wrong in your setup. What TeX distribution are you using? Are you sure it's up-to-date?

Comment: Hi, I am using TeXstudio 2.9.4 and MikTex 2.9, installed via ProText 3.1.5. Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please give a complete example.

Answer (score 1):

The following document produces a single page document with the text `a` in texlive 2016 lualatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
a
\end{document}
```

If you get `lmrlmrlmsslmtt` (which will be code accidentally typesetting the default latin modern family names `lmr`, `lmss`, `lmtt`) then post the file list that it produces in the log.

It should look like

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2016/03/26 v6465 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2016/05/18 v6512 L3 Experimental document command parser
luaotfload.sty    2016/04/21 v2.7 OpenType layout system
fontspec-luatex.sty    2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2016/06/02 v1.0s Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2016/06/04 v0.01d Graphics/Color for luaTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
fontspec.cfg
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
luatex-loader.sty    2016/05/16 v0.6 Lua module loader (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```